# MVC Bootstrap glyphcon and navbar

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I am trying to get a Shopping glyphcon near the "Shop" ActionLink, and this is what I get: [image: This is what happening]

I want the home icon to be before the "Shop" and in the same line.
I'm using MVC5 .cshtml file

This is the Code:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

            @* Glasses Menu *@
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Glasses <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("InfinityAR", "InfinityAR", "Glasses")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Google Glass", "GoogleGlass", "Glasses")</li>
                    @*<li class="divider"></li>             //TODO: Enter here something
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>*@
                </ul>
            </li>

            @* SDK's Menu *@
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Developers <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li style="margin-left:10px">SDK</li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("METAIO", "Metaio", "Developers")</li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="@Html.ActionLink("Shop", "Shop", "Glasses")"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" /></a>
            </li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
        </ul>
        @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've confused what HTML.ActionLink() does. It generates the anchor link with tags.
So if you inspect the generated HTML code of this line:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Shop", "Shop", "Glasses")
```

It will produce something like this:

```
<a href="glasses/shop">Shop</a>
```

Your code will produce something like this:

```
<a href="<a href="glasses/shop">Shop</a>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" /></a>
```

You want to use the URL.Action() helper:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Shop", "Glasses")"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Shop</a>
```

Comment: Thank You Problem Solved!  but I found one problem in your solution, if you close the `<span>` like this `/>` the design will lost. you need to close it like the VS close it automatically `</span>`

Comment: Ahh sorry I didn't notice that. You can't close spans like that. I'll update the solution.